# Package’s local.xml not loading when a custom theme with local.xml is active

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I have a design package from [ThemeForest](http://themeforest.net/) installed, which has been working just fine, but I am trying to create a new custom theme that consists of a `custom.css` stylesheet, and a `local.xml` layout file which only adds a reference to `custom.css`.

In Magento Admin, the value of ***System > Configuration > General > Design / Package / Current Package Name*** is set to the design package I installed. That works fine until I set ***Design / Themes / Default*** to my new custom theme, which causes the `local.xml` file of the design package to be ignored. I can verify this by removing the `local.xml` of my custom theme or by replacing it with the one from the design package.

The same thing happens when I set ***Design / Themes / Layout*** to another theme, now the `local.xml` file from the package, and the one from ***Design / Themes / Default*** are ignored. I could work around this problem by combining the contents of all the `local.xml` files into a single one under ***Design / Themes / Layout***, but that’s obviously not a desirable solution.

I have made custom themes before but this is the first time I have had this problem, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Same thing happens when I add a second theme and themes=>layout to this theme. now the local.xml file of the package and the default theme are ignored.
A workaround for this problem would be putting the content of the local.xml files in a single file and set that as layout but that's obviously not a need solution.

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

You have run into a limitation of [Magento’s design fall back hierarchy](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy#2). The way it works is to search backwards from most specific location, to least specific.

> ... if your custom theme calls for a CSS file called ‘styles.css’ but the Magento application is unable to find the file in your custom theme, Magento will go to the next theme in the hierarchy to find the file ... it will continue working down the hierarchy of themes until it’s able to locate the file called ‘styles.css.’
>
> This method of building design is called fall backs, because the application ‘falls back’ to the next possible source of required files in order to retrieve and load a requested file.

What this means for you is that the layout file `local.xml` can only be sourced from one location, and it will be whatever is the most specific to the current theme. So Magento will search for it in the following priority:

1. `app/design/frontend/$package/$theme/layout/local.xml`
2. `app/design/frontend/$package/default/layout/local.xml`
3. `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`

The important thing to realize is that each of these files *overrides* the next one down, rather than adding to them. I have heard that Magento 2.x may address this situation, but for 1.x we need to work around this.

### A Possible Solution

The way I would go about solving this is to create a simple extension that just loads your custom css file in a separate layout file. Then you do not need the `local.xml` file in your new theme and it will continue to fall back to `default`.

**app/etc/modules/My_Theme.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Theme>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Theme>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/My/Theme/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Theme>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Theme>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_theme>
                    <file>my_theme.xml</file>
                </my_theme>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/$package/$theme/layout/my_theme.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/my_theme.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This uses Magento’s design fall back method to load the file as well. So you could put this at `skin/frontend/$package/$theme/css/my_theme.css` or in the `$package/default/css/` subdirectory.

Comment: I always thought local.xml was the only file which was indeed a collection of all the local.xml files. But if it isn't all my previous templates didn't have a local.xml so my custom theme one was the only one.

Comment: @thommie - I have run into the same wish that Magento could load `local.xml` from multiple design tiers because it would make inheritance easier. Did my solution work for your situation?

Comment: @thommie as said by fantasticrice, it is clear to understand the wish. But what you need to get in this whole process is that it in not inheritance, indeed but fallback. If something is not found (layout xml, image, css, js, phtml, ...) it falls back to his "parent" to get the file. Once the file is found, there is no more fallback to be done. Please also note that the fallback scheme has changed for version 1.9+ of Magento - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html#changes-fallback

Comment: that solution helped me for the "local.xml is not used" problem. Thanks!